# pythonのtk.Frameの使い方について

Tags: python, tkinter

tk.Frameの使い方について、よく以下のような記述が紹介されています。

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.geometry("300x200")
        frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        frame.pack()
        canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width=500, height=500, background="white")
        canvas.create_oval(200, 100, 10, 20, fill='black')
        canvas.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

class Application(tk.Frame)
の部分でtk.Frameの継承を行ってるんだと思いますが、
ここの恩恵がどこで得られているのかわからず。

途中でframe = tk.Frame(self.master)のように別でインスタンス化しているのであれば、継承しなくとも以下のような記述でも同じことができると思うのですが、継承する意味があるのか、どうも理解ができない状況です。

```
import tkinter as t

root = t.Tk()

class APP:
    def __init__(self,widget):
        self.widget = widget
        self.inttt()

    def inttt(self):
        frame = t.Frame(self.widget)
        frame.pack()

        canvas = t.Canvas(frame,width=200,height=500,bg="white")
        canvas.pack()

app = APP(root)
```

どなたか上記の違いがわかるかたはいらっしゃいますか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

`tk.Frame` クラスを継承している場合、以下の様に書くこともできます。

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.geometry("300x200")
        self.pack()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=500, height=500, background="white")
        self.canvas.create_oval(200, 100, 10, 20, fill='black')
        self.canvas.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

tk.Frameを継承しなくてはならない理由はほぼないと思います。

参考事例では、継承クラスがApplicationというクラス名だったのでしょうか？
クラス名から機能が判断できないので、参考にするにはちょっと考えものです。

もし継承させたFrameクラスに、共通のウィジット配置やマウスイベントをバインドするなど機能的な共通点を記述して使いまわすならば、恩恵はわかりやすいと思います。

継承Frameクラスを用いて、GUI上にいくつかFrameを並べ、似たような機能を付与するなどです。